# Expansion of conditional probability with $X$ and $Y$

Tags: statistics, expected-value, conditional-probability, conditional-expectation

Question
$\mathbb{E}(X^2 +Y | Y =2)  $

Whereas the answer is
$\mathbb{E}(X^2|Y =2)+2$

Where did I go wrong? What would your approach be?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I do not see a difference of two squares here, and also how a factorization of $X^2 + Y$ could help here. On the other hand, every conditional expectation $\mathbf E[- \mid \mathfrak A]$ is linear. Hence
$$ \def\E#1{\mathbf E\left[#1\right]} \E{X^2 + Y \mid Y = 2} = \E{X^2\mid Y = 2} + \E{Y \mid Y =2} = \E{X^2\mid Y = 2} + 2 $$
To discuss your solution here, you should write down your calculations.